# What is "Total - Display Select" in Google Adwords?

Tags: google-ads

I'm trying to learn how to use Google Adwords for the first time.  I open a campaign and look at my keywords.  The thing I don't understand is the item circled in red below:
[image]

What is "Total - Display Select" and why is it the number 4?  How is that number 4 calculated?  If you sum up all the cells above it in that column, it doesn't give you the number 4.  I was expecting the number 1 because I only see 1 click in the first row, which is properly summed up in the row "Total - all but removed keywords".  So I don't know what "Total - Display Select" is trying to report on.

Comment: https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/7193800

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Display Select" refers to clicks from ads showing up off of Google search and not associated with a keyword.   They show up on Google partner websites that have a topic that closely matches the keywords.  Here is an article that explains the feature: https://3qdigital.com/3q-accelerate/4-things-need-know-display-select

This feature appears to be similar to the "content network" option that lets ads show up on AdSense websites.

Answer (score -2):

I think it`s how many clicks you got on your  Display Network campaigns

Comment: Such a short answer is not high quality.  This answer could be improved a lot just by finding Google's documentation and linking to it.